# python telegram bot modules (telebot)

Tags: python

I have written a simple example bot with telebot module but I do not know how I should fix this problem.  My code is :

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.testBot("699870969:AAHth6QQWI8GR2CuCyW9V98F3CXUIA2siAw")

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
   bot.reply_to(message, "hesam, how are you ?")


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_all(message):
   bot.reply_to(message, message.text)

bot.polling()
```

> ERROR : the telebot module has no attribute for test bot

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have misspelled the [`TeleBot`](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/telebot/__init__.py#L97) class name. See [the example](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/3d5ef5b1d8ece102080f67469d4f0e747fcbe10e/examples/echo_bot.py#L8).

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong METHOD name

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("699870969:AAHth6QQWI8GR2CuCyW9V98F3CXUIA2siAw")
```

or

```
from telebot.async_telebot import AsyncTeleBot
bot = AsyncTeleBot('TOKEN')
```

AND LAST BUT not LEAST **DO NOT POST YOUR TOKEN** BAKA JANEYO?

Answer (score 0):

```
TOKEN = "YOUR_TOKEN"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
```

try this, you have an error. and **remember not to show the TOKEN to others**